# View last queries in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

How can I see the last queries for a MySQL DB?

I am a DB administrator. For example, when an application queries the DB, how they can be viewed?

Answer (score 4):

On a development database, you can enable the query log:

```
mysqld_safe --log &
```

This will create a log in the data directory with your machine's hostname. If you then do something like tail -f on the log (at least in the Unix world, not sure about Windows), you'll be able to see the queries as they are happening.

I said "development," because I don't think there is a way to do this in the production system that won't cause production to come to a halt.

Comment: You can run it on a production server for debugging if you don't have a development environment. 

It all depends on how busy the server is and how much room you can spare for the log. 

If you're only running it for a short period or longer on a quiet database it should be fine. I don't see that enabling the log necessarily leads to the production server coming to a halt.

Answer (score 3):

You can enable the query log as mentioned.  If you want to log particular messages on a system under development you could run the development system through the [mysql proxy](http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/MySQL_Proxy).  Basically it is a service that can sit between the mysql server and client(s).  There are many code samples about how to log or manipulate data based on criteria you set.

Comment: +1 for mentioning MySQL Proxy.